# Receive Ethernet data to the FPGA

Tags: fpga, ethernet, phy

I have Lattice ECP3 Versa Evaluation Board.

My objective is to connect Ethernet to the FPGA and be able to receive data (and later to send data) successfully. I don't really care on what protocol I will receive the data at, lets assume I want to receive UDP packets.

The PHY that presented on the board is: Marvell 88E1119R Gigabit Ethernet transceiver.

Lattice has Tri-Speed Ethernet MAC IP core that from my understanding using this IP implements the Data Link layer in the OSI model.

[image]

I added this IP core and connected the pins that coming from the PHY to the Ethernet interface using this figure and table:

[image]
[image]

So all left me to do is to program the 'User Host Logic' and 'User Application Logic' according to this figure from the Tri-Speed Ethernet User Guide from Lattice.

OK so I start to program the host user logic:

programmed some random MAC address: AC-DE-48-00-00-80
and few more other internal register flags.
finally asserted the receive enable signal (rx_en).

I getting some feedback from the Host Interface telling me that I'm receiving broadcast frames and short frames, but when I looking at the signals coming to my FPGA, its all just zeros.

The RJ45 led is blinking with orange led (its mean that the Ethernet interface is alive right?)

What should be my next step? How can I receive data to my FPGA through the Ethernet?
How can I know my MAC address? Or I should to choose the address like I did inside the FPGA.
How can I know what is my FPGA port and/or IP address?

I will be glad for any help and leads for how to make this Ethernet happen.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is currently far too broad to be answerable here.  Before you do anything, note that having a device which uses only fixed logic (and not a stored program processor) be on a conventional IP-style network is extremely unusual and rarely of benefit. Before there were better choices using raw Ethernet for a special purpose might have made sense, unlikely now.  Typically you'd only do this as part of constructing a "computer" inside your FPGA, either soft core or hard core if your FPGA is hybrid.  If you want to pursue this, try to find a complete example project as a starting point.

Comment: The first step should be to read the entire PHY datasheet and then read the try speed MAC IP core. There are software registers in the core that have the MAC address. The best way is to use an evaluation board project and modify that for the FPGA you have. It took me about 20 hours to do the reading and implement the project for an Altera board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are I think confusing a couple of different levels of the stack here, I mean UDP sits on top of IP (generally), and IP needs among other things you to respond to ARP and advertise an IP address to MAC mapping.

At a bare minimum you need to set a MAC address (which at a minimum must be unique within your network), and then generate ethernet frames containing this MAC, trouble is your OS will not want to do this (But may be able to be coerced) and any switches will drop the packets because you do not have an ARP responder to advertise that you have that MAC (Broadcast packets MIGHT work).

Getting ARP and ping working are generally the way to go when bringing up an FPGA based IP implementation. Once you have those, UDP will come easily. Lots of state machines in your future....

Comment: Thanks Dan. So as I said in my question, I think I already set an MAC address using the User Host Logic. So you telling me I need to make ARP and PING interface working in the FPGA? any leads how to make it?                                                        and another question, how can I make sure that I set the MAC address right (beside talking with the internal registers of the IP which I already doing).

Comment: IP level protocols (IP as in "Internet Protocol" not the FPGA/ASIC terminology of a licensed core) and above are typically a *software* function.  Do you have software in your system yet?  It's going to be very hard to do this without something in the FPGA running some, realistically apart from special purpose optimizations it's typically only usefully done with a processor core running an operating system, not uncommonly Linux though there are more compact solutions which *could* work if there were a true need.

Comment: @ChrisStratton No I dont have microcontroller on my board, just FPGA. I cant make the FPGA and PC (connected with Ethernet) communicate without the software? lets assume I dont need IP, just data to transfer between the PC and the FPGA

Comment: @ChrisStratton While it is usually done in software, because that is just easier, I have done enough of an IP stack to support a UDP stream in each direction in pure fabric logic. The use case was a SDR streaming IQ data at pretty close to the wire speed limit. Look at the HPSDR Hermes code for an example (done on Cyclone 3 IIRC), they even wrote the MAC layer.

Comment: Yes, there are special purposes I alluded to in my comment on the main question, but there are also typically better solutions for those today (USB, etc).  Especially for an unfamiliar user, IP-over-Ethernet is unlikely to make sense without a processor.  Arbitrary "data transfer" of a likely fairly low rate might be better achieved by SPI or something like a USB FIFO chip used as a sort of logic analyzer that can write, too.  Much is missing from the question about what sort of data is to be transferred, why, and **what sort of machine in the FPGA would ultimately use or produce it.**

Comment: The information here about MAC addresses is false. Linux is just fine at generating raw Ethernet packets (it's unusual but completely fine). You also don't need to respond to ARP to say that you have a MAC. Switches broadcast packets *by default*, if they don't know where that MAC address is.